# Return Data After S3 Upload in Node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous

I finally have file uploads working through Node and the AWS SDK...there's just one thing that's missing now that I haven't been able to crack yet, which is that I need to get the URL to the newly uploaded file on S3 and save it to my database.

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

  const fileContent = Buffer.from(req.files.listPDF.data, 'binary');

  const params = {
    Bucket: 'my_bucket',
    Key: filename,
    Body: fileContent
  };

  s3.upload(params, function(err, data){
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  });
```

I'm guessing it's promise-related, but I haven't had success with "await" yet. The data parameter in the function has a "Location" attribute, which I need. Originally, I was trying to set a previously-declared var to it. However, it wasn't doing anything since the upload was not yet completed. If anyone's grappled with this and cracked the code, I'd really appreciate your thoughts!

Comment: All major AWS JavaScript SDK functions have a `.promise()` variant so you can await the result. But your current code should work fine too - just write the S3 object key (or info from the returned `data`) to your DB in the upload callback.

Comment: Thanks! I will have to look into the promise variant. I did try using that data within that function, but to no avail, so maybe the promise variant is the way to go. I appreciate your time and knowledge!

Comment: @jarmod what's the reason that location is not get in res bcz the POC i did i always got Location from both way's.